# Print list of leaves of a tree using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I need to write a function where I need to return a list of the leaves of the tree.

So for this tree:

```
        1
    2       3
 4       5     6
```

This should print [4, 5, 6]

Here's what I've come up with so far. I can't seem to find how to get back to the function. It only print [4]

```
def fringe(root):

    if root.left:
        return fringe(root.left)
    elif root.right:
        return fringe(root.right)
    else:
        return [root.key]
```

Any inputs?

Answer (score 6):

Use `yield` to create a generator:

```
def fringe(root):

    if root.left or root.right:
        if root.left:
            for key in fringe(root.left):
                yield key
        if root.right:
            for key in fringe(root.right):
                yield key
    else:
        yield root.key

print list(fringe(mytree))
```

In newer versions of python, instead of

```
for key in fringe(root.left):
    yield key
```

You can use:

```
yield from fringe(root.left)
```

Comment: The idea is right, but this won't work either. This will either go left, or go right, or yield the current node.

Comment: You're dead right, fixed. (Didn't check his logic before modifying his code)

Comment: Note that "newer versions of Python" means the current development trunk.  No released version supports `yield from` yet.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because if you have left leaf then you don't look at right one at all. Try this one

```
def fringe(root):
    result = []
    if root.left:
        result.extend(fringe(root.left))
    if root.right:
        result.extend(fringe(root.right))
    if not result:
        result = [root.key]
    return result
```